# How to use Node js with cordova in my website?

Tags: node.js, cordova

I have a an website which is hosted on
live server and i installed the `Node.js` and `Cordova` in my live server. I want to get some hardware information
using the `cordova` i decide to use this plugin for get some user information.Now My doubt is, can i use this 
`cordova` in my websites(because after some researching i know that its used for make a mobile apps)? and if yes means how to start the Node server automatically?

some of SO posts say  first create a site then what type of feature need add the appropriate feature in your website using some plugins.This is what i needed how its possible?How the node server run?

Comment: Have you found any reference that Cordova runs externally to a mobile device?

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry bro, i did not get anything related like that.after RND maximum results say 'NO'

Comment: One option is to include the required cordova plugins into your source node folder and deploy the complete folder to your server. Similar to : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/09/07/cordova-browser-compatibility-with-MFP/

Comment: @Keerthi Thanks for the link, what is MFP server we need to buy that??Actually i already used browser commend for platform

Comment: MFP server is another cordova plugin. I have shared the above link only as a sample. So just the way cordova-plugin-mfp (which is a cordova plugin) is added in the nodejs source, you can add the plugin folder that you need in the same way.

Comment: okay okay..so we need deploy ? its enough??

Comment: any links regarding this..??